# MATLAB callback when saving figure file

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-guide

I need to check programmaticall whether a fig (guide) file was saved or not, so bascially I need a callback when:

```
myfigure_SavedCallback(hObject, varargin)
```

I didn't find anything online, so I guess it is not possible, can someone verify this?

**SOLVED:**

So I just found out how to do this by myself. In the guide editor you can open the `Toolbar Editor` and change all the icon-buttons a gui usually has. There is somewhere the field `Clicked Callback`. You can enter the regular callback-formalism, e.g.

```
mygui('uipushtool2_ClickedCallback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

And add this callback to the code. In that particular callback, a UD-flag for saved/unsaved can be handled if necessary.

Comment: You should post the solution you found as an answer, not as a part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know there is no callback for figures (or other HG components) that executes when they are saved.

However, I think you might be able to work around this. You can create an object of your own that executes code when it is saved - something like this:

```
classdef mytest < handle    
    methods         
        function sobj = saveobj(obj)
            sobj = obj;
            disp('saved') % Put your code here
        end        
    end    
end
```

Then you can create one of these objects, and store it in, for example, the `UserData` property of the figure. When the figure gets saved, so does the object, and whatever code you would like will get executed.

I imagine that there may be some ways in which the above workaround might be defeated by various things that the user could do. But with some care, it might be enough for your needs.

Comment: Interessting, however, I found out you actually CAN pass a callback to the save function, see the edited post.

Comment: Perhaps the solution mentioned in your edit meets your needs. But it's not really a callback on the figure, it's just adding your own save functionality to the GUI with a toolbar button. In particular, it won't get executed if the user manually saves the GUI figure using a `saveas` or `hgsave` command at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the image was saved manually:

You can check if the `Filename` field of the figure is empty or not. As soon as the figure is saved it get the path of the saved figure.

Run the code and save the figure manually yourself.

```
clc
close all
clear

img = imread('cameraman.tif');

h = figure(1);
imshow(img);

while(isempty(h.FileName))
    clc
    disp('not saved yet');
    pause(0.3)
end

disp('saved in:');
disp(h.FileName);
```

this will give you:

```
not saved yet
saved in:
C:\Users\samuel\Desktop\fig.fig
>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, unfortunately that is absolutely not what I was looking for. I don't know what the user will name the fig-file, so I can't check if it already exists. I did mention in the question, that I need to run some code just after saving a fig-file (it is a guide-fig file)...

Comment: Well, you need to identify the figure somehow, just use a boolean which starts by false and gets true when the user saves it.

Comment: THAT is my question, how do you find out the figure was saved?

Comment: Sorry, that is way too banal. Again my question: How can I check whether the user has saved an image MANUALLY. Therefore I need a callback or whatever to check WHEN the user is saving a file.

Comment: Again, that won't work since it is a GUIDE fig file! Those already have a FileName and saving them as another file does not change the "FileName" property.

Comment: Does your guide has the save button?

Answer (score 0):

So I just found out how to do this by myself. In the guide editor you can open the Toolbar Editor and change all the icon-buttons a gui usually has. There is somewhere the field Clicked Callback. You can enter the regular callback-formalism, e.g.

```
mygui('uipushtool2_ClickedCallback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

And add this callback to the code. In that particular callback, a UD-flag for saved/unsaved can be handled if necessary.